# How to read the txt as points in mathematica

Tags: import

I have the following txt file and want to import it as 18 points in Mathematica, so that I can draw the points on a complex plane. Each line (except for the first line `100` and blank line) in the txt file is a point with its real and imaginary parts. For example, the points presented in the file are

$(1.004786849932060e-01+i*1.093556972652714e+00),(-1.004786849932060e-01+i*-1.093556972652714e+00), (9.976096134274947e-20+i*-1.192941404973469e-19), (-1.480297485865874e+00+i*7.422776004582909e-02),...$

```
100

1.004786849932060e-01 1.093556972652714e+00
-1.004786849932060e-01 -1.093556972652714e+00
9.976096134274947e-20 -1.192941404973469e-19
-1.480297485865874e+00 7.422776004582909e-02
-1.480297485865874e+00 7.422776004582909e-02
-1.000000000000000e+00 -5.551115123125783e-17

-8.393828623433014e-01 -8.910743549375130e-02
8.393828623433014e-01 8.910743549375130e-02
-2.564013936414357e-21 -4.714327574115172e-23
5.664048419599507e-01 -1.320526392429827e-01
5.664048419599508e-01 -1.320526392429827e-01
-1.000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000e+00

-1.182775851427075e+00 2.322257341019021e+00
1.182775851427075e+00 -2.322257341019021e+00
5.693577648965902e-20 -1.430540343549141e-19
-2.491786138158304e+00 -1.102305635983134e+00
-2.491786138158304e+00 -1.102305635983134e+00
-1.000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000e+00
```

Could anyone help?

Thank you a lot!

Moreover, is it possible to draw the points with 6 different color (if the point is in the first line of a block, then we use red; if the point is in the second line, then we use yellow,....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = ReadList["C:/test.txt", Number] // Rest // Partition[#, 2] & //
    Complex @@@ # & // Chop
```

> ```
> {0.100479 + 1.09356 I, -0.100479 - 1.09356 I, 0, -1.4803 + 
>   0.0742278 I, -1.4803 + 0.0742278 I, -1., -0.839383 - 0.0891074 I, 
>  0.839383 + 0.0891074 I, 0, 0.566405 - 0.132053 I, 
>  0.566405 - 0.132053 I, -1., -1.18278 + 2.32226 I, 
>  1.18278 - 2.32226 I, 0, -2.49179 - 1.10231 I, -2.49179 - 
>   1.10231 I, -1.}
> ```

```
ComplexListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: My pleasure, thanks for the accept. If there is one number per line (and missing either real or complex part), then explore `ReadLine` in conjunction with `Interpreter`.

Comment: thanks!! is it possible to draw the points with 6 different color (if the point is in the first line of a block, then we use red; if the point is in the second line, then we use yellow,....)? should I open a new question or just update this one?

Comment: `dataColored = Transpose[Partition[data, 6]]` and `ComplexListPlot[dataColored, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Orange, Blue, Green, Purple, Cyan}]` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!